# Passing a generic List<T> as a delegate parameter

Tags: c#, events, generics, type-conversion

I wrote an event which is supposed to pass a List with generic items of type (T) to all subscribers:

```
public delegate void GenericListItemCountChangedEvent(List<Object> sender, GenericListItemCountChangedEventArgs e);
public event GenericListItemCountChangedEvent GenericListItemCountChanged;

private void RaiseGenericListItemCountChanged<T>(List<T> List) where T : BaseElem {
    if (GenericListItemCountChanged != null)
        GenericListItemCountChanged(List as List<Object>, new GenericListItemCountChangedEventArgs(typeof(T)));
}
```

This is a statement from a class, which subscribes to the event above:

```
 _catalog.GenericListItemCountChanged += (sender, e) => GenericListItemCountChanged(sender, e);
```

And this is the method the event is forwarded to inside the subscriber:

```
private void GenericListItemCountChanged(List<Object> sender, Catalog.GenericListItemCountChangedEventArgs e) {
    Catalog.ListTypes changedListType = Catalog.GetListTypeFromList(changedList); 
    //GetListTypeFromList expects parameter to be a type of <T> where T : BaseElem
}
```

Obviously, a `List<Object>` cannot be converted to a `List<T> where T : BaseElem`.

I'll accept your answer if you could provide a solution for retrieving the List with items of their "real" type inside the method, which handles the event.
(Restoring original List state)

The "real" type of the items inside the list is stored inside the EventArgs.
But I don't know if that could help me...

**SOLUTION:**
I could not have figured this out without the help of @ChrFin, thanks mate!

*public class Catalog : Object*

```
public delegate void GenericListItemCountChangedEvent(IEnumerable<BaseElem> sender, GenericListItemCountChangedEventArgs e);
public event GenericListItemCountChangedEvent GenericListItemCountChanged;

private void RaiseGenericListItemCountChangedEvent<T>(List<T> List) where T : BaseElem {
    if (GenericListItemCountChanged != null) {
        GenericListItemCountChanged(List, new GenericListItemCountChangedEventArgs());
    }
}
public void ForceRaiseGenericListItemCountChangedEvent<T>(List<T> List) where T : BaseElem {
    RaiseGenericListItemCountChangedEvent(List);
}

public class GenericListItemCountChangedEventArgs {
    public GenericListItemCountChangedEventArgs() {
    }
}
```

- 

```
    public static ListTypes GetListTypeFromList<T>(IEnumerable<T> List) where T : BaseElem {
        Type typeofT = List.GetType().GetGenericArguments()[0];
        //typeofT now contains correct subtype of 'BaseElem'
        return ListTypes.SomeType //based on 'typeOfT'
    }
```

*public partial class MainWindow : Window*

```
    _catalog.GenericListItemCountChanged += (sender, e) => GenericListItemCountChanged(sender, e);
```

- 

```
private void GenericListItemCountChanged(IEnumerable<BaseElem> sender, Catalog.GenericListItemCountChangedEventArgs e) {
            Catalog.ListTypes changedListType = Catalog.GetListTypeFromList(sender);
            //We now know the changed ListType
}
```

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two (three) ways to solve this: [Covariance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee207183.aspx) and generics:

1) Generics:
You also need to create a generic delegate:

```
public class YourClass<T> where T : BaseElem
{
    public delegate void GenericListItemCountChangedEvent<T>(List<T> sender,
                             GenericListItemCountChangedEventArgs e);
    public event GenericListItemCountChangedEvent<T> GenericListItemCountChanged;

    private void RaiseGenericListItemCountChanged<T>(List<T> List)
    {
        if (GenericListItemCountChanged != null)
        {
            GenericListItemCountChanged(List,
               new GenericListItemCountChangedEventArgs(typeof(T)));
        }
    }
}
```

Of course you can then only use one explicit type of base type `BaseElem` in this case.

2) Covariance:
Using the [`IEnumerable<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9eekhta0%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) interface instead of the explicit type to support covariance:

```
public delegate void GenericListItemCountChangedEvent(IEnumerable<BaseElem> sender,
                         GenericListItemCountChangedEventArgs e);
public event GenericListItemCountChangedEvent GenericListItemCountChanged;

private void RaiseGenericListItemCountChanged(IEnumerable<BaseElem> List)
{
    if (GenericListItemCountChanged != null)
    {
        var itemType = List.Count() > 0 ? List.First().GetType() : typeof(BaseElem);
        GenericListItemCountChanged(List,
            new GenericListItemCountChangedEventArgs(itemType));
    }
}
```

3) Ugly, but would work: Casting:

```
public delegate void GenericListItemCountChangedEvent(List<BaseElem> sender,
                         GenericListItemCountChangedEventArgs e);
public event GenericListItemCountChangedEvent GenericListItemCountChanged;

private void RaiseGenericListItemCountChanged<T>(List<T> List) where T : BaseElem
{
    if (GenericListItemCountChanged != null)
    {
        GenericListItemCountChanged(List.Cast<BaseElem>().ToList(),
            new GenericListItemCountChangedEventArgs(typeof(T)));
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for helping the second time this week :) Your first snippet doesn't work for me, because the class, wich fires the event is Catalog : Object. Your second snipped may work but I am unsure of how to use the IList<BaseElem> in the subscription. Basically how to get the List<BaseElem> from the IList<BaseElem>

Comment: @NoelWidmer: `Basically how to get the List<BaseElem> from the IList<BaseElem>` - you can't (see the linked article about covariance)! (Note my update to `IEnumerable<T>` as I just found out `IList<T>` does not support covariance) You need to work with the interfaces in that case as the explicit types are NOT the same and can't be "globaly casted", but only on a "per item bases" (see 3rd option). Do you need specific `List<T>` methods/extensions or what is the reason you can't work with `IEnumerable<T>`?

Comment: I do not have much experience with Interfaces. That is why I don't know if a 'IEnumerable<T>' works. I'd like to recieve a 'List<T>' in 'GetListTypeFromList();' and I cannot change this method to expect an 'IEnumerable<T>' since it is used quite often. I guess I cannot get 'List<T>' from 'IEnumerable<T>'?

Comment: @NoelWidmer: You can - see the `ToList` in my third example. But this creates a new list => slow if you have mayn items or do it very often. Why can't you change the method? `List<T>` implements `IEnumerable<T>` => you do not need to change the calls to the method...

Comment: Yes! I was able to do it. In case you are interested: I updated the question with a specific solution